# this memory alloc. code runs perfectly on x86, but periodically causes segfaults on Android

Tags: android, c, debugging, memory-management, android-ndk

I am having a hard time tracking down a bug in native C code within my Android application.  This code sits in Wireshark, which I've ported to Android.  I have run this same code on x86 numerous times under Valgrind and GDB and can never find a problem with it.  However, when it runs on Android, it seems to behave differently and cause segmentation faults every so often (e.g., after running ~100 times).

To be honest, I do not understand the syntax of the code that well, so I'm having a hard time understanding what assumptions might have been made about an x86 machine that do not hold about an ARM-based processor.

Essentially, what it tries to do is bypass constantly allocating new memory and freeing it, by placing memory in to a "bucket" and allowing it to be reused.  Whether or not this is actually better in terms of performance is a separate question.  I'm simply trying to adopt pre-existing code.  But, to do so, it has a couple main macros:

```
#define SLAB_ALLOC(item, type)          \
  if(!type ## _free_list){        \
    int i;            \
    union type ## slab_item *tmp;     \
    tmp=g_malloc(NITEMS_PER_SLAB*sizeof(*tmp)); \
    for(i=0;i<NITEMS_PER_SLAB;i++){     \
      tmp[i].next_free = type ## _free_list;  \
      type ## _free_list = &tmp[i];   \
    }           \
  }             \
  item = &(type ## _free_list->slab_item);    \
  type ## _free_list = type ## _free_list->next_free;

#define SLAB_FREE(item, type)           \
{                 \
  ((union type ## slab_item *)item)->next_free = type ## _free_list;  \
  type ## _free_list = (union type ## slab_item *)item;   \
}
```

Then, a couple supporting macros for specific types:

```
#define SLAB_ITEM_TYPE_DEFINE(type)     \
  union type ## slab_item {     \
    type slab_item;       \
    union type ## slab_item *next_free; \
  };

#define SLAB_FREE_LIST_DEFINE(type)   \
  union type ## slab_item *type ## _free_list = NULL;

#define SLAB_FREE_LIST_DECLARE(type)    \
  union type ## slab_item *type ## _free_list;
```

Does anyone recognize any assumptions on x86 that might not fly on an Android phone?  Eventually what happens is, SLAB_ALLOC() is called and it returns something from the list.  Then, following code attempts to use the memory, and the application segfaults.  This leads me to believe it's accessing invalid memory.  It happens unpredictably, but it always happens in the first attempt to use memory that SLAB_ALLOC() returns.

Comment: Data alignment, most likely. On ARM, int's and pointers should be aligned on 4-byte coundary, shorts - on 2-byte. Otherwise segfault.

Comment: Without getting into tracing the code, I am curious if you are freeing the slabs correctly at some point?  I could see android running out of memory sooner than a PC.  Also, some malloc implementations allocate a little extra so you could read out of bounds without error on the PC whereas other platforms might complain, but I don't see anywhere that would happen.

Comment: Is it consistently happening AFTER ~100 cycles, or does it sometimes happen on the first few calls?

Comment: thanks for the responses, all.  interesting on data alignment, I wasn't aware of that!  I am assuming they are freed correctly, no different than x86.  But it really may be the case that Android is running out of memory sooner.  It doesn't happen consistently after 100, it could be tens or hundreds or thousands, its unpredictable.

Comment: I'm going to try replacing this code with straight malloc() and free() calls, and see if I still have issues with this...

Comment: Just junk this code and replace it with simple calls to `malloc` and `free`. Between the gcc statement-expressions (invalid C), the hideous multi-line macros, and the premature optimization, you should be embarrassed to have this code in your project.

Comment: after replacing these with malloc and free, I no longer have this issue.  So, it has to be something with data alignment or memory management.  Does someone want to make an answer regarding this so I can accept it and assign some karma?

Comment: The union type should take care of the alignment issues, assuming the initial allocation from `g_malloc` is properly aligned (which it might not be), I suggest you try using `malloc` there instead of `g_malloc`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're simply running out of memory? The `SLAB_ALLOC` macro calls `g_malloc` which aborts if the allocation fails.